How to get a stream in flutter from data retrieved from MongoDB database using Node server?
I want a mongodb query to return snapshots like how this firebase query returns:
Stream<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> getChatMessages(String chatRoomId) {
    return _firestore
        .collection('chats')
        .doc(chatRoomId)
        .collection('messages')
        .orderBy('timestamp', descending: true)
        .snapshots();
  }

I tried creating a stream in node where everytime there is a change in user data i am console logging it. How do I create a stream in flutter so that I can use it in a StreamBuilder to listen to real-time updates?
const getStream = asyncHandler (async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { id } = req.params;
    const user= await User.findOne({ _id: id }).exec(); // Execute the query to get the actual document
    const changeStream = user.collection.watch(); // Get the collection from the document and create a change stream
    changeStream.on('change', (data) => {
      console.log(data);
    });
    res.status(200).json({ message: 'success' });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.status(500).json({ message: 'error' });
  }
});


What you're trying to do is actually very complicated, and requires the use of a websocket or some sort of HTTP server push mechanism.  It won't be a simple API endpoint like you're showing now.  Firebase just makes it look easy because it's doing all the hard work for you in both the backend and client SDK.
